# Difference in two methods, one with this param

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the difference in these two methods?

```
public static string Mrthod1(this Controller controller)
{
    return GetStringDate(controller, null, null);
}
```

and

```
public static string Mrthod1(Controller controller)
{
    return GetStringDate(controller, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Ref. [Extension Methods (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

It makes calls like `myController.Mrthod1()` possible:

> Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.

`this` before first method parameter specifies which type you're *extending*:

> Their first parameter specifies which type the method operates on, and the parameter is preceded by the `this` modifier.

So your method is an extension method on `Controller` class and allows you to call it like if it was an instance method on all `Controller` class (and all derived classes) instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Mrthod1(this Controller controller)
{
    return GetStringDate(controller, null, null);
}
```

is an extension method. This will always be inside a static class:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string Mrthod1(this Controller controller)
    {
        return GetStringDate(controller, null, null);
    }
}
```

which allows you to perform calls like this:

```
string myString = controller.Mrthod1();
```

If the `this` keyword was removed and you needed to call `Mrthod1`, you'll need to specify the class, also:

```
string myString = MyClass.Mrthod1(controller);
```